# Saving a Postman header value into a variable throughout requests in a collection

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, postman

I am trying to automate my test suite in Postman so that I don't have to manually go into each request and change that header value to what I initially put in the first request.

My test suite currently looks like:

First Request:

```
var headerValue = postman.setGlobalVariable('Number', headerValue);
console.log("Number is: " + headerValue);
```

Second Request Header:

```
Number - {{headerValue}}
```

I would expect headerValue to have the value of 'Number' since I have set it as a global variable but it is coming back as undefined. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 48):

This is how you can do this

If Refresh_token is the header value

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("refresh_token",postman.getResponseHeader("Refresh_token") );
```

Official Documentation: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples

Comment: This answer uses code that is now deprecated.  You should use `pm.globals.set("Number", pm.response.headers.get("Number"));`.

Answer (score 34):

It seems like @Sai's answer <s>does not work</s> is not recommended anymore, since `getResponseHeader` is deprecated now. The updated code is:

```
pm.test("First request", function() {
    let headerValue = pm.response.headers.get("Number")
    pm.globals.set("Number", headerValue);
});
```

In the second request go `Headers` section, add a new header with `Number` as a key and `{{Number}}` as a value.

Comment: This should be accepted answer as of Postmant 7.34.0 `getResponseHeader` does not exist on `pm` object.

Comment: I would also add that if the variable is contained in the collection scope, not global, it should be `pm.collectionVariables.set("Number", headerValue)`.

Answer (score 5):

Just as an addition to *Rostyslav Druzhchenko*'s answer. In Postman Client you can add this directly in the ***Tests*** tab:
[image: postman ui]

Answer (score 1):

No, try this way. For postman, if you want to set environment or global variable just use (key,value ) pattern this way-

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable(key,value) or   
postman.setGlobalVariable(key,value)
```

and finally grab them using {{key}}

```
var headerValue = ”your value goes here”;
postman.setGlobalVariable('Number', headerValue);
```

and use {{Number}} on your sub subsequent request header

Comment: Currently getting a 'Number' is not defined doing it this way in the console still

Comment: Is there a postman.getHeader method or a method that is similar to that? I'm trying to get the value of a header in my header request instead of hard coding it in the test suite

Comment: @jmcconnell `postman.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"); //Note: the getResponseHeader()` method returns the header value, if it exists. and more about methods here https://www.getpostman.com/docs/testing_examples

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach with logging of you header before saving it to variable:

```
let authToken = postman.getResponseHeader("Authorization")
console.log("auth header -> ", authToken)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("auth", authToken)
```